# More efficient way to remove elements from an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have developed a array list something like this

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("1");
list.add("8");
list.add("8");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
```

Now my question is: if I want to remove the "8"s from the list, which way is better?

first way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(list.get(i).equals("8")) {
        list.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

second way:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
        if(iterator.next().equals("8"))
            iterator.remove();
```

Now please advise which one of them is more efficient and faster from performance point of view and also is there any other way that is something like built in function by using it we can remove duplicate without iterating that much.

Comment: add to set duplicate are removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance wise they should be similar. Have you tested?
If you want to use the built in methods, you can do this with a similar performance.(to be confirmed by testing):

```
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("8"));
```

Finally if you want a list without duplicates, use a Set as others have mentioned.

Comment: This will be less performant than OP's code. `list.remove` will start from the beginning of the list every time -- O(n^2) instead of OP's O(n).

Comment: list.removeAll(Collections.singleton("4")); this is also good I think

Answer (score 5):

If you just need a set of numbers, then use `HashSet` and not a `List`. If you need to preserve the order by which you are putting the numbers, use `LinkedHashSet`. As for removal, always prefer the version with the `iterator`, even though in your particular case the performance may be comparable. The idiom with `iterator` is more widely applicable than indexing, for example if you used a `LinkedList`, indexing would result in disastrous performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the duplicates I suggest you to use `Map<Integer,Integer>` where the 1st Integer is the key and the 2nd is the number of key occurences . So when you add the key that already exists you just increment the corresponding counter. (In remove operation you doing vice - versa). When you need all the distinct values, you just use [Map.keySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)().