# Removing duplicates from a list without iterating over it or using a set

Tags: java, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More efficient way to remove elements from an array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370464/more-efficient-way-to-remove-elements-from-an-array-list)

I have developed an array list

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

       list.add("1");
       list.add("2");
       list.add("3");
       list.add("3");
       list.add("5");
       list.add("6");
       list.add("7");
       list.add("7");
       list.add("1");
       list.add("10");
       list.add("2");
       list.add("12");
```

Now what I was trying to remove duplicate elements from it but this time I do not want to convert it into set or having an iteration loop in list itself , what I was trying any built in method of List or Collections class that will remove the duplicates or is there any other way to achieve this , please advise, thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how you could remoe duplicates without doing any iteration on the list elements.

Comment: @assylias, No its a different scenario all toughener man

Comment: @JBNizet yeah that is also I am looking .

Comment: @user1363946: *Why* do you not want to use a set or iterate? If you want a collection without duplicates, you simply shouldn't be using ArrayList...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah you are right but I was trying sort of R&D , in which this is the present scenario..

Comment: Well you shouldn't expect a type to contain operations which are only useful if you're using the wrong type to start with. If you want to use the wrong type, you'll have to do the work yourself.

Comment: Maybe you can investigate the use of Collections.frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o), which give you number of elements equals to o in c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is simply no solution for what you're asking. Don't use `List` in the first place - use `Set`. If you're concerned about preserving order of insertions, there is `LinkedHashSet`. If you need to return `List` from the method - use `LinkedHashSet`, and then convert it into `List`; or consider returning `Collection`, not `List`.

Answer (score -3):

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();

...

list = list.Distinct().ToList<String>();
```

Comment: Are sure this is Java code? What is a List object?

Comment: That's [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)

Comment: @Prabu.. similar some thing will work for java

Comment: @Prabu that what I am searching dude..!!